# pytest.postgresql external template database

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, pytest

I am trying to write database integration tests against a dockerized postgresql database, the schema of which I would rather not replicate in my own test setups. In pytest-postgresql documentation there is a mention of the following option:

> You can also define your own database name by passing same dbname value to both factories.
>
> The way this will work is that the process fixture will populate template database, which in turn will be used automatically by client fixture to create a test database from scratch. Fast, clean and no dangling transactions, that could be accidentally rolled back.
>
> Same approach will work with noproces fixture, while connecting to already running postgresql instance whether it’ll be on a docker machine or running remotely or locally.

But I don't seem to be able to figure out how this is really supposed to work. Is there anywhere a full working example of it? It would be real nice to be able to just copy the existing database in the container for my tests to run in.

When I give my no_proc factory and client factory the same db name, I run into a "database already exists" issue. In the stack trace there there is a "create database ... template" call, that tries to use a db with a suffix of _tmpl. It almost sounds like there should be a parameter to tell what is the db to be created and what the template is...